# Disallow user to change tweet text after clicking tweet button

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am working on famous **snake-game**. There is Tweet button to tweet your score on twitter. I have implemented to tweet the score which you gain by playing the game.

Now the problem is when anyone clicks the tweet button to tweet his/her score it opens with Twitter's tweet text area with some text and his/her current score.  The issue is that I don't want the user to change his/her current score which they gained by playing.

Example: Suppose I played the game and score 230 (some random score) and when I click the tweet button I get the tweet text area with **score: 230** but I can also change the score in this tweet box. 
How to disallow user to change his/her score?

I am also looking other way to implement this. Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: [HTML <textarea> readonly Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_textarea_readonly.asp)

Comment: @Redu, the <textarea> is not in my current DOM. After tweet button, it comes. So this will not work.